# SSH to EC2 instance timedout

Tags: networking, ssh, amazon-ec2, terraform

I created an AWS EC2 instance to set up prometheus on it, I created a new ssh keypair and provisioned the instance using terraform, I used instance type as "t3.large" and an SSD disk of 120GB and the OS is Ubuntu 18.04, and I could ssh to the instance normally. Until now everything is okay.

After some time installing Prometheus and Grafana using docker, I get back to the instance and I find that I'm unable to login!! I'm getting the following issue:

```
ssh: connect to host [ip] port 22: Connection timed out
```

I'm sure that this is not internet connection issue, as I'm able to ssh to other instances. and the issue is the same when using the ip address or DNS, the port 22 is open too.

This is the terraform script I used, but I don't think it's related to this:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "ubuntu" {
  key_name   = "ubuntu"
  public_key = file("ubuntu.pem.pub")
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ubuntu" {
  name        = "ubuntu-security-group"
  description = "Allow HTTP, HTTPS and SSH traffic"

  ingress {
    description = "SSH"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "HTTPS"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "HTTP"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "HTTP"
    from_port   = 3000
    to_port     = 3000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "HTTP"
    from_port   = 9090
    to_port     = 9090
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "HTTP"
    from_port   = 9100
    to_port     = 9100
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }



  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "terraform"
  }
}


resource "aws_instance" "ubuntu" {
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.ubuntu.key_name
  ami           = "ami-0dc8d444ee2a42d8a"
  instance_type = "t3.large"

  tags = {
    Name = "ubuntu-prometheus"
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.ubuntu.id
  ]

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("key")
    host        = self.public_ip
  }

  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = 120
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "ubuntu" {
  vpc      = true
  instance = aws_instance.ubuntu.id
}
```

Comment: Are your security groups good? I lock down SSH to my IP address - if you do that, has your IP address changed?

Comment: Yes, security group is good and the public ip address is always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue and I got access to my EC2 instance again with all the data as I left as it is.

The reason behind this issue is that in order to allow http traffic in a new port I used `ufw` which enables the firewall, and the rule for allowing ssh is not included in `ufw` which causes losing access. I could have used aws security groups and added the right rule to avoid all of this.

The solution was to create a new EC2 instance and mount the volume of the old EC2 instance to this new created instance.

list the available disks as follows:

```
buntu@ip-172-31-27-78:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 97.8M  1 loop /snap/core/10185
loop1         7:1    0 28.1M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
nvme0n1     259:0    0  120G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  120G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:2    0  120G  0 disk 
└─nvme1n1p1 259:3    0  120G  0 part
```

After this mount your partition to any directory:

```
$ sudo mkdir /data
$ sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /data/
```

Now you will be able to access your volume files, in order to allow ssh access edit the the files `user.rules` and `user6.rules` located in the directory `/data/etc/ufw` and add these lines:

```
#user.rules
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

```
user6.rules
-A ufw6-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw6-user-input -p udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Kudos to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370732/cant-ssh-into-aws-ec2-after-enabling-firewall) who helped me a lot, and I collected all the steps here.